# How can I recognize a running batch file in task manager?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, scheduled-tasks, task-manager

I run a few batch files as SYSTEM (as services) and they appear as cmd.exe in tasklist. Sometimes I need to terminate one of them but I cannot decide which cmd.exe to terminate.

Plus; I run many batch files as scheduled tasks, all appear as cmd.exe (with my account)

How can I mark a batch file, so I can recognize it at task manager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

open Task Manager, click on the Processes tab, and select `View->Select Columns...`. Turn the checkbox `Command Line` on. Now Task Manager will show you, for each cmd.exe, what it is running. For a batch file this looks like

```
cmd /c ""C:\path\to\test.bat""
```

For your question on making sure only a single instane can run, this rather dirty trick works:

```
@echo off

tasklist /v | find /I /c "MyUniqueTitle" > nul
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto ErrorAlreadyRunning

title MyUniqueTitle
echo "Running as Single Instance!"
goto end


:ErrorAlreadyRunning
echo "ErrorAlreadyRunning"

:end
pause
```

Comment: oops seems you removed the single instance question already :]

Comment: That "MyUniqueTitle" label may work...

Comment: It takes about 10 seconds to get the tasklist on my pc. In that time, a second instance could start.