# Only one instance of batch

Tags: batch

I found this script here it works great but problem is because I like to set a path where that lock file is stored, like D:\mylogs.
But this script make a log where it is runned from and that is not ok.
Any help to change this script so I can select my own folder for lock files?

[How can I prevent to run same batch file twice to allow only one instance?](https://superuser.com/questions/362212/how-can-i-prevent-to-run-same-batch-file-twice-to-allow-only-one-instance)

How to change this code so I can select where locl file is created. Because now it is created where script is started, but I want lock file in my folder like D:\script Can anyone help please?

```
:init
set "started="
2>nul (
 9>"%~f0.lock" (
  set "started=1"
  call :start
 )
)
@if defined started (
    del "%~f0.lock" >nul 2>nul
) else (
    echo Process aborted: "%~f0" is already running
    @ping localhost > nul
)

exit /b




:start
cd /d %~dp0
:: REST OF THE SCRIPT
```

Comment: Change the path where the lock file is created. It's right there. Just change it and you're done? What's the actual question?

Comment: Read `help call` and [online](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Change all occurences of `"%~f0.lock"` to `"D:\mylogs\%~n0.lock"`

Comment: Seth I trieed that and doesn't work

Comment: how to use set path = D:\mylogs instead of this??? "Change all occurences of "%~f0.lock" to "D:\mylogs\%~n0.lock" " Also this doesn't work I tested it D:\mylogs\%~n0.lock

Comment: What actually happens when you do it?

Comment: when I change script with this "D:\mylogs\%~n0.lock". It say that process already exist, but it doesn't.