# run batch file only when the same process is not in progress

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, task-manager

I would need to run batch when user logs in, but if any other cmd.exe is running, then batch won't execute.
Maybe something similar to this: [How can I recognize a running batch file in task manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/362164/how-can-i-recognize-a-running-batch-file-in-task-manager?rq=1). But I would need no action if some other cmd.exe is running.

Thank you for help

Comment: Are you in control of the other processes? If so, are the scheduled through Task Scheduler?

Comment: That's strange. There's nothing preventing you from running multiple `cmd` shells at the same time. You need to provide more information. What error message do you get when running the second batch file?

Comment: @Papa Yes, they run vie Task Scheduler every time user logs in batch file is executed and sometimes process isn't exited (if user use just win+L) in these cases I would like to stop batch from executing again. (No error when batch running for second time).

Comment: Can you show your batch file? Are you using `START`? This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/how-do-i-run-a-bat-file-in-the-background-from-another-bat-file/8351295#8351295